# How to retry connecting to database after internet connection has been switched off after some time

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have an notification application built in c# for notifying any change in database . the application runs in the background . But the problem is after the start of the application if the internet is switched off the application throws an SQLException . i have used try catch to handle the exception . but i want my application to try connecting the database and when the connection is established it returns to the main code .

```
    try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection =
       new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                {              
//i want to return here when the connection is reestablished

using (SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand(GetListenerSQL(), connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        // Make sure we don't time out before the
                        // notification request times out.
                        command.CommandTimeout = NotificationTimeout;
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            messageText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])reader.GetValue(13)).ToString();
                            // Empty queue of messages.
                            // Application logic could parse
                            // the queue data and 
                            // change its notification logic.
                        }

                        object[] args = { this, EventArgs.Empty };
                        EventHandler notify =
                        new EventHandler(OnNotificationComplete);
                        // Notify the UI thread that a notification
                        // has occurred.
                        this.BeginInvoke(notify, args);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(SqlException e)
            {

            }
```

is it possible to do it without goto statement . i would prefer avoiding the goto statement .

Comment: I assume the above code is in a function, so you just want to wait a sensible amount of time (whatever suits your situation) and then execute the code again.  Put this wait and execute in the catch block.

Comment: You could try using [NetworkChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange?view=netframework-4.7) class to monitoring internet connection.

Comment: put the whole of the try in a while {...  loop.  have a flag to set on success to break out of the loop

Comment: @Archer okay thanks i got a plan to do it from your suggestion . Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the retry logic out of the query method. I've seen a good retry library somewhere, but I can't find it just now.

```
public void StartListener()
{                    
    var message = GetMessage(); 
    //process message in some way
    object[] args = { this, EventArgs.Empty };
    EventHandler notify = OnNotificationComplete;                
    this.BeginInvoke(notify, args);                     
}

private const int TimeoutStep = 2000;
private const int MaxTimeout = 10000;

private string GetMessage(int timeout = 0)
{
    //prevent loop of endless retries
    if (timeout >= MaxTimeout)
    {
        //optional: define your own Exception class
        throw new MaxTimeoutException();
    }

    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        return GetMessageFromDatabase();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //log ex in debug mode at least               
        return GetMessage(timeout + TimeoutStep);
    }             
}

private string GetMessageFromDatabase()
{
    string message = null;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(GetListenerSQL(), connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandTimeout = NotificationTimeout;

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    message = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])reader.GetValue(13));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from the suggestion of @Archer i got the solution . in the catch block i call the method again which uses this connection after some suitable time . Something like

```
public void StartListener()
{
try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection =
       new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                {              
//i want to return here when the connection is reestablished

using (SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand(GetListenerSQL(), connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        // Make sure we don't time out before the
                        // notification request times out.
                        command.CommandTimeout = NotificationTimeout;
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            messageText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])reader.GetValue(13)).ToString();
                            // Empty queue of messages.
                            // Application logic could parse
                            // the queue data and 
                            // change its notification logic.
                        }

                        object[] args = { this, EventArgs.Empty };
                        EventHandler notify =
                        new EventHandler(OnNotificationComplete);
                        // Notify the UI thread that a notification
                        // has occurred.
                        this.BeginInvoke(notify, args);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(SqlException e)
            {
                 Thread.Sleep(2000);
                 StartListener();
            }
}
```

Comment: This will cause an endless loop if the connection is lost. This might block your application.

Comment: any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If its an failure you should call an timer and the timer should call the backgroundworker.
Write the Functionality to check the connection in the backgroundworkers. if it goes for true you should stop the timer. And call the usual process